# Oracle RAC, unable to connect to node vip

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, clustering, rac

I have a new oracle RAC installation running 11.2.0.4 on redhat 6. I can connect to sqlplus from a client using the node name but it is timing out when i use the node vip

eg. first one works, second one doesn't

```
sqlplus system/xxxxxxx@csya-orarac1.xxxx-dmz.local:/dev1.xxxx-dmz.local
sqlplus system/xxxxxxx@csya-orarac1-vip.xxxx-dmz.local:/dev1.xxxx-dmz.local
```

i can successfully ping and run an nslookup against the VIP

the local_listener looks like this

```
local_listener                       string      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(AD
                                                 DRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=csya
                                                 -orarac1-vip.xxxx-dmz.local)(P
                                                 ORT=1521))))
```

i can successfully ping between the 2 node vip names from the servers themselves.
the VIP is defined in the `/etc/hosts` file, and the node vip shows when performing an `ipconfig`

```
eth1:5    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:85:60:79
          inet addr:172.28.1.95  Bcast:172.28.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

the listener on the node, knows of the vip ip address

```
./lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 11-MAY-2015 11:13:45

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTENER)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     listener
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
Start Date                11-MAY-2015 10:26:10
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 47 min. 35 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/csya-orarac1/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=LISTENER)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.28.1.91)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.28.1.95)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "+ASM" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+ASM1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "dev1.xxxx-dmz.local" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "dev11", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "dev1XDB.xxxx-dmz.local" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "dev11", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

this is part of a bigger issue i have been having with connecting to the SCAN name, but using the oracle trouble shooting doc [975457.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=191953414348712&id=975457.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=wm3ct8t7m_4#aref_section21) it looks like it may be a local listener problem with the vip

any ideas?

Comment: At this point I usually check with telnet, if the client can communicate at all with the listener, e.g. from the client: `telnet csya-orarac1-vip.xxxx-dmz.local 1521`. Note that the listener is not prepared for telnet connections, but you should be able to connect, get a prompt and then quit/abort connection, instead of getting timed out.

Comment: Hi, i am getting a "could not open connection..." message when trying to telnet to the VIP, is this potentially something i need to ask my network administrator to look at?

Comment: Usually a firewall restriction, ask the network administrator to let communication through for the 1521 port on the VIP addresses from your client.

Comment: Almost certainly a firewall problem

Comment: problem solved, it was a firewall issue, only the node ip addresses where allowed through the firewall, i now have the VIP and cluster IP addresses added to our firewall rule and can now connect via both the VIP, and more importantly the cluster. Thanks for all the help. I will write this up as the answer so others can see it.

Comment: i don't agree that this question should be put on hold (then again i wouldn't as it's my question). I'm sure other people have had issues with firewalls, especially as often the DBA is separate from the network administrator. The DBA therefore needs to be aware of issues which are outside of the usual sphere of DBA influence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with the VIP addresses not being allowed to be accessed via port 1521 due to our firewall policy. These IPs are now permitted and the problem has been resolved. thanks to [Balazs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/28019/balazs-papp) for all the help/